# How to show line number when executing csh script?

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I am using csh script and I want to see the line numbers when executing csh script in debug mode.
I am doing like

> csh -x script_name

What do I have to do apart from this to see line numbers in debug mode?

Comment: Google for "Csh considered harmful"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Google for "maintaining legacy code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in feature to do this. The only method I can think of is (ab)using the `postcmd` special alias. This alias will be run after every command:

```
set _lineno = 0
alias postcmd '@ _lineno++ && echo -n $_lineno\ '

echo a
echo b
echo c && echo d
```

Outputs:

```
% csh test.csh
1 2 a
3 b
4 c
d
```

Unfortunately, this will clutter the `-x` output:

```
% csh -x test.csh
set _lineno = 0
alias postcmd @ _lineno++ && echo -n $_lineno\ 
@ _lineno++
echo -n 1 
1 @ _lineno++
echo -n 2 
2 echo a
a
@ _lineno++
echo -n 3 
3 echo b
b
@ _lineno++
echo -n 4 
4 echo c
c
echo d
d
```

Which we can sort of filter with `grep`:

```
% csh -x test.tcsh | & grep -Ev '^(@ _lineno|echo -n [[:digit:]]+)
set _lineno = 0
alias postcmd @ _lineno++ && echo -n $_lineno\ 
1 @ _lineno++
2 echo a
a
3 echo b
b
4 echo c
c
echo d
d
```

All of this is less than perfect, and may not even work very well with large scripts...

As you've asked a number of `csh` related questions for the last few days:

While `tcsh` can work fine as an interactive shell, `tcsh` or `csh` is generally not well suited for scripting tasks. There are many things missing, incomplete, or simply behave in a "strange" way. It's even *more* ugly than normal shell scripting with POSIX (and that's saying a lot).

Unless you have a good reason not to (such as maintaining existing scripts), you probably should give up on `csh` for now, and go with either a "real" programming language (Python, Ruby, Perl, whatever), or use `/bin/sh`, `bash`, or `zsh`.

Comment: yes you are right its not working with large csh script. And my reason to stick to csh is my existing product using this. So no option but to bear this pain.

Comment: @Dharmendra Okay, just wanted to make that clear :-) I feel for you ;-) Perhaps you can hack on this to make it work (not sure what the problem is?) ...

Comment: in tcsh, postcmd runs BEFORE a command, not after (because, reasons???) unlike zsh where it's intuitively correct. whereas, in tcsh, precmd runs after the command (but before next prompt, which is why i assume it's named this weird way)

Comment: Please DO NOT recommend people drop csh!!! Many companies mandate its use as a shell!

Comment: That doesn't change that it's ill-suited for scripting tasks @user234461; and even as an interactive shell it's not all that super.

Comment: @MartinTournoij No! Companies mandate its use for scripting as well! You are stirring up trouble! It may be difficult to use as an interactive shell but there are entire systems built around using CSH scripts with the CSH shell. People have spent hours upon hours of their lives trying to use them. By recommending people avoid csh for future projects you are throwing all that effort back in their faces.

Comment: That people have invested time in this is besides the point and still does not change that the fact that it's objectively a very constrained and bad programming environment @user234461. I don't know the situation you or anyone else is in; so I answered the asked question and gave some advice in case people are unaware of any of this.