# Error line number and file name in csh

Tags: csh

I try to run `rungms` C Shell script, which is a part of [GAMESS](http://www.msg.ameslab.gov/gamess/). This script is rather complicated and it runs other CSH scripts from the GAMESS distribution. One of the scripts says:

```
@: Expression Syntax
```

How can I determine which script on which line produces the error? Is it possible in C Shell?

For example Bash prints errors in this way:

```
node02:/stor > cat erroneous.sh 
#!/bin/sh

[!-z $0] && "This is incorrect line"
node02:/stor > sh erroneous.sh 
erroneous.sh: line 3: [!-z: command not found
```

Can I make CSH do something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show line number when executing csh script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833687/how-to-show-line-number-when-executing-csh-script)

Comment: The short answer is that this is not possible, but see the above link for an attempted workaround that may or may not work....